translation invariance of expectation value of hit counting variable for Lévy process
Let $(X_t)_{t \in [0, \infty)}$ a $\mathbb{R}$- valued
Markov process (in my question I'm primary interested in dealing with Lévy process), $s, a, u >0$,
$I(a) := 
\{[k \cdot a, (k+1) \cdot a] \ : \ k \in \mathbb{Z} \} $ the
family of $a$-integral tiles covering $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $M_u(a,s)$ the random variable counting the number of tiles
$[k \cdot a, (k+1) \cdot a]$ in $I(a)$ hit by
$(X_t)$ at some time $t \in [u,u+s]$. The
notion is introduced in the paper
"Hausdorff Dimension Theorems for Self-Similar Markov Processes"
by Luqin Liu and Yimin Xiao (online available) in lemma 3.1 for Markov processes.
My question is if for
$(X_t)_{t \in [0, \infty)}$ a $\mathbb{R}$- valued non deterministic(!)
Lévy process the expectation value of $M_u(a,s)$ is
"translation invariant" in the sense that
$$\mathbb{E}[M_u(a,s)]= \mathbb{E}[M_0(a,s)] $$
i.e. the expectation value of the number of hit tiles
$[k \cdot a, (k+1) \cdot a]$ in $I(a)$ from $I(a)$ by
$(X_t)$ at some time $t \in [u,u+s]$ is the same as
the expectation value of the number of hit by
$(X_t)$ at some time $t \in [0,s]$?
I asked identical question in mse.

Do you have a response to the answer below?

No, this is not true is general. For instance, if $(X_t)$ is a Poisson process of intensity (say) $\lambda=1$, then
$$M_u(a,s)=\lfloor X_{u+s}/a\rfloor - \lceil X_u/a\rceil + 2.$$
So,
$$EM_{1/2}(2,2)=2.593\ldots\ne2.534\ldots=EM_1(2,2).\quad\Box$$

More generally, here
$$EM_u(2,s)=\frac{1}{4} \left(e^{-2 (s+u)}+2 s+e^{-2 u}+6\right),$$
which is strictly decreasing in $u$.
